# Level: Hard - Extract data from XML in a hierarchy format

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

I've researched and have not come up with anyone doing anything like this.  I'm open to suggestions.  Right now I am trying to load a table described below.

```
    CREATE TABLE [Course].[Navigation](
        [NavigationId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [ParentID] [int],
        [ChildID] [int], 
        [Type] [varchar](100) NULL,
        [Label] [int] NULL,
        [Id] [varchar](100) NULL )
```

Which represents a navigational chart for a course.

The XML that I'm trying to load is:

```
        <navigation>
            <content label="Introduction">
                <content label="Intro" id="000286_1001"/></content>
            <content label="Premature Atrial Contractions">
                <content label="Description" id="000286_1002"/>
                <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1003"/>
                <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1004"/></content>
            <content label="Wandering">
                <content label="Description" id="000286_1005"/>
                <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1006"/>
                <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1007"/></content>
            <content label="Ectopic Atrial Rhythm">
                <content label="Description" id="000286_1008"/>
                <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1009"/>
                <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1010"/></content>
            <content label="Supraventricular Tachycardia">
                <content label="SVT" id="000286_1011"/>
                <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1012"/>
                <content label="Multifocal Atrial Tachycardia">
                    <content label="Description" id="000286_1013"/>
                    <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1014"/>
                    <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1015"/></content>
                <content label="Ectopic Atrial Tachycardia">
                    <content label="Description" id="000286_1016"/>
                    <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1017"/>
                    <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1018"/></content>
                <content label="Ectopic Atrial Tachycardia with Block">
                    <content label="Description" id="000286_1019"/></content>
                <content label="Atrial Flutter">
                    <content label="Description" id="000286_1020"/>
                    <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1021"/>
                    <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1022"/>
                    <content label="Treatment" id="000286_1023"/></content>
                <content label="Atrial Fibrillation">
                    <content label="Description" id="000286_1024"/>
                    <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1025"/>
                    <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1026"/>
                    <content label="Signs" id="000286_1027"/>
                    <content label="Treatment" id="000286_1028"/></content>
                <content label="AVRT">
                    <content label="Description" id="000286_1029"/>
                    <content label="Pathophysiology" id="000286_1030"/>
                    <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1031"/>
                    <content label="Etiology" id="000286_1032"/></content>
                <content label="AVNRT">
                    <content label="Description" id="000286_1033"/>
                    <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1034"/>
                    <content label="Etiology" id="000286_1035"/></content>
                <content label="Treatment" id="000286_1036"/></content>
            <content label="Review">
                <content label="Quick Quiz" id="000286_1037"/></content>
            <content label="Conclusion">
                <content label="Summary" id="000286_1038"/></content>
        </navigation>
```

Comment: This XML is... not great. Why are all the elements using attribute labels and there are no actual elements? Does it have to be in this format? Of course it's going to be hard when the XML is not close to the standard...

Comment: This is how a 3rd party app creates it.  I thought just like you ....this stinks.  However it's all I have to work with.

Comment: I have hundreds of these files to parse in the same format.

Comment: Well I feel extremely sorry for you. I would suggest starting with OPENXML in SQL. I think you are going to immediately run into issues though. Your best bet may be to run a script or macro to re-format your XML file before processing...

Comment: @JacobH `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist). Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Comment: @Shnugo thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a recursive query, handling the nested `<content>` deeper and deeper:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<navigation>
  <content label="Introduction">
    <content label="Intro" id="000286_1001" />
  </content>
  <content label="Premature Atrial Contractions">
    <content label="Description" id="000286_1002" />
    <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1003" />
    <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1004" />
  </content>
  <content label="Wandering">
    <content label="Description" id="000286_1005" />
    <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1006" />
    <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1007" />
  </content>
  <content label="Ectopic Atrial Rhythm">
    <content label="Description" id="000286_1008" />
    <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1009" />
    <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1010" />
  </content>
  <content label="Supraventricular Tachycardia">
    <content label="SVT" id="000286_1011" />
    <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1012" />
    <content label="Multifocal Atrial Tachycardia">
      <content label="Description" id="000286_1013" />
      <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1014" />
      <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1015" />
    </content>
    <content label="Ectopic Atrial Tachycardia">
      <content label="Description" id="000286_1016" />
      <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1017" />
      <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1018" />
    </content>
    <content label="Ectopic Atrial Tachycardia with Block">
      <content label="Description" id="000286_1019" />
    </content>
    <content label="Atrial Flutter">
      <content label="Description" id="000286_1020" />
      <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1021" />
      <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1022" />
      <content label="Treatment" id="000286_1023" />
    </content>
    <content label="Atrial Fibrillation">
      <content label="Description" id="000286_1024" />
      <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1025" />
      <content label="Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment" id="000286_1026" />
      <content label="Signs" id="000286_1027" />
      <content label="Treatment" id="000286_1028" />
    </content>
    <content label="AVRT">
      <content label="Description" id="000286_1029" />
      <content label="Pathophysiology" id="000286_1030" />
      <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1031" />
      <content label="Etiology" id="000286_1032" />
    </content>
    <content label="AVNRT">
      <content label="Description" id="000286_1033" />
      <content label="ECG Features" id="000286_1034" />
      <content label="Etiology" id="000286_1035" />
    </content>
    <content label="Treatment" id="000286_1036" />
  </content>
  <content label="Review">
    <content label="Quick Quiz" id="000286_1037" />
  </content>
  <content label="Conclusion">
    <content label="Summary" id="000286_1038" />
  </content>
</navigation>';
```

The query will use a concatenated *sequence* (thx to John Cappelletti!) first to get the original order, secondly this can be used as id and parentId

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Lvl
          ,nc.value(N'@label','nvarchar(max)') AS Label
          ,nc.value(N'@id','nvarchar(max)') AS id
          ,CAST(REPLACE(STR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),3),' ','0') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Seqnc
          ,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentSeqnc
          ,nc.query('./content') AS Deeper
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/navigation/content') AS A(nc)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT recCTE.Lvl+1
          ,nc2.value(N'@label','nvarchar(max)') AS Label
          ,nc2.value(N'@id','nvarchar(max)') AS id
          ,recCTE.Seqnc+REPLACE(STR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),3),' ','0')
          ,recCTE.Seqnc
          ,nc2.query('./content') AS Deeper
    FROM recCTE
    CROSS APPLY recCTE.Deeper.nodes(N'content') AS A(nc2)
)
SELECT Lvl
      ,id
      ,Seqnc
      ,ParentSeqnc
      ,Label  
FROM recCTE
ORDER BY Seqnc;
```

The result

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| Lvl | id          | Seqnc     | ParentSeqnc | Label                                 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1   | NULL        | 001       | NULL        | Introduction                          |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1001 | 001001    | 001         | Intro                                 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1   | NULL        | 002       | NULL        | Premature Atrial Contractions         |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1002 | 002001    | 002         | Description                           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1003 | 002002    | 002         | ECG Features                          |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1004 | 002003    | 002         | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1   | NULL        | 003       | NULL        | Wandering                             |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1005 | 003001    | 003         | Description                           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1006 | 003002    | 003         | ECG Features                          |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1007 | 003003    | 003         | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1   | NULL        | 004       | NULL        | Ectopic Atrial Rhythm                 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1008 | 004001    | 004         | Description                           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1009 | 004002    | 004         | ECG Features                          |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1010 | 004003    | 004         | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1   | NULL        | 005       | NULL        | Supraventricular Tachycardia          |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1011 | 005001    | 005         | SVT                                   |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1012 | 005002    | 005         | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | NULL        | 005003    | 005         | Multifocal Atrial Tachycardia         |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1013 | 005003001 | 005003      | Description                           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1014 | 005003002 | 005003      | ECG Features                          |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1015 | 005003003 | 005003      | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | NULL        | 005004    | 005         | Ectopic Atrial Tachycardia            |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1016 | 005004001 | 005004      | Description                           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1017 | 005004002 | 005004      | ECG Features                          |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1018 | 005004003 | 005004      | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | NULL        | 005005    | 005         | Ectopic Atrial Tachycardia with Block |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1019 | 005005001 | 005005      | Description                           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | NULL        | 005006    | 005         | Atrial Flutter                        |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1020 | 005006001 | 005006      | Description                           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1021 | 005006002 | 005006      | ECG Features                          |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1022 | 005006003 | 005006      | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1023 | 005006004 | 005006      | Treatment                             |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | NULL        | 005007    | 005         | Atrial Fibrillation                   |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1024 | 005007001 | 005007      | Description                           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1025 | 005007002 | 005007      | ECG Features                          |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1026 | 005007003 | 005007      | Etiology/Symptoms/Treatment           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1027 | 005007004 | 005007      | Signs                                 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1028 | 005007005 | 005007      | Treatment                             |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | NULL        | 005008    | 005         | AVRT                                  |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1029 | 005008001 | 005008      | Description                           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1030 | 005008002 | 005008      | Pathophysiology                       |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1031 | 005008003 | 005008      | ECG Features                          |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1032 | 005008004 | 005008      | Etiology                              |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | NULL        | 005009    | 005         | AVNRT                                 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1033 | 005009001 | 005009      | Description                           |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1034 | 005009002 | 005009      | ECG Features                          |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 3   | 000286_1035 | 005009003 | 005009      | Etiology                              |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1036 | 005010    | 005         | Treatment                             |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1   | NULL        | 006       | NULL        | Review                                |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1037 | 006001    | 006         | Quick Quiz                            |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1   | NULL        | 007       | NULL        | Conclusion                            |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
| 2   | 000286_1038 | 007001    | 007         | Summary                               |
+-----+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I think I have 4 levels in this mess.  Wow, thank yous so much for looking at this.....

Comment: @PatrickStewart the recursive approach will traverse down to any level, as long as the structure is the same...

Comment: @PatrickStewart As you are new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say *Thank you*, but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are  - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Comment: @PatrickStewart You were lucky to get Shnugo's attention on this question.  I will upvote for you, but ONLY you can ACCEPT the answer.